# django accessing values from a list in a template

Tags: python, django

My web page when viewed is currently blank, looking at other samples it seems i am accessing the values correctly but im not getting any data. 
i have checked my lists by printing them, and they both have plenty of data in them

template

```
{% extends 'oncall/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for pol in lstPolicy %}
        <h2>1 - {{ pol.Name }}</h2>
        {% for user in lstUsers %}  
            {% if user.Policy == pol.Name %}
                <h3>2 -{{ user.Level }}</h3>
                <p> 
                    Mobile: {{ user.Mobile }}
                    From: {{ user.StartTime }} on {{ user.StartDate }}
                    Until: {{ user.EndTime }} on {{ user.EndDate }}
                </p>
            {% endif %} 
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

base template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IT on call Rota</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

view

```
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    lstPolicy = []
    lstUsers = []
    for objPolicy in objPolicyData['escalation_policies']:
        strPolicyName = objPolicy['name']   
        if strPolicyName.lower().find('test') == -1:
            classPolicy = Policy()
            classPolicy.Name = strPolicyName
            lstPolicy.append(strPolicyName) 
            for objOnCall in objPolicy['on_call']:
                classUser = User()
                classUser.Policy = strPolicyName
                strLevel = ''
                if objOnCall['level'] == 1:
                    strLevel == 'Primary on call'
                elif objOnCall['level'] == 2:
                    strLevel == 'Backup on call' 
                elif objOnCall['level'] == 3:
                    strLevel == 'Tetiary on call'
                classUser.Level = strLevel
                classUser.StartDate = getDate(objOnCall['start'])
                classUser.EndDate = getDate(objOnCall['end'])
                classUser.StartTime = getTime(objOnCall['start'])
                classUser.EndTime = getTime(objOnCall['end'])
                objUser = objOnCall['user']
                classUser.Name = objUser['name']
                classUser.Mobile = getUserMobile(objUser['id'])
                lstUsers.append(classUser)   
    return render(request, 'oncall/rota.html', {'lstUsers': lstUsers, 'lstPolicy': lstPolicy})
```

html generated

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IT on call Rota</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/">Home</a>


        <h2>1 - </h2>












        <h2>1 - </h2>












        <h2>1 - </h2>












        <h2>1 - </h2>












        <h2>1 - </h2>













    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you'd make your code a little cleaner if you could pass objOnCall to your User constructor

Comment: @alecxe added base template

Comment: @alecxe im not sure what you mean? ive added the html to question that the code generates, it looks like the template are working, but not getting the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add **strPolicyName** :

```
lstPolicy.append(strPolicyName)
```

but you must add **classPolicy**:

```
lstPolicy.append(classPolicy)
```

A string doesn't have **Name** property :)

Comment: you welcome  :). A little offer: don't use 'class' in object names.